# Optional <Integer> cannot be converted to Int (for use on GUI Progress Bar)

Tags: java, swing, stream, option-type, jprogressbar

I am receiving below error, when I try to set value on a JProgressBar.

> "Optional  cannot be converted to Int"

Could someone please advise any workarounds/Solution??

```
public GUI(){
    initComponents();
    tL = new TasksToDo();
    jProgressBar1.setValue(tL.retrieveTotalHours());// [Where my error occurs]}
}
```

And from the TaskToDo Class, Originally I set this to ArrayList but the warnings said needed to switch to Optional:

```
  public class TasksToDo {

    public static ArrayList<Task> taskList;

    public TasksToDo(){
        taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
        taskList.add(new Task(0,"Whitepaper", "Write first draft of Whitepaper",  7));
        taskList.add(new Task(1,"Create Database Structure", "Plan required fields and tables",  1));
        taskList.add(new Task(2,"Setup ODBC Connections", "Create the ODBC Connections between SVR1 to DEV-SVR",  2));

    }

    public void addTask (int taskId, String taskTitle, String taskDescription,  int taskHours){}

    public ArrayList<Task> retrieveTask(){
        return taskList;
    }

    public Optional<Integer> retrieveTotalHours(){
    return taskList.stream().map(e -> e.getTaskHours()).reduce(Integer::sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to unwrap the optional and grab the value in it like this. Otherwise you can't assign an `Optional` where `int` is needed.

```
tL.retrieveTotalHours().orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

An Optional means that the value need not be there. It is basically there to force the caller to explicitly decide what to when a value does not exist. In your case, you can specifify a default value:

```
jProgressBar1.setValue(tL.retrieveTotalHours().orElse(0));
```

However, your `retrieveTotalHours` method probably should not return an Optional in the first place. `Stream.reduce` returns `Optional.empty()` when the stream is empty, but in your case it probably should return `0` when the list of tasks is empty. So you can do:

```
public int retrieveTotalHours(){
    return taskList.stream().map(e -> e.getTaskHours()).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

(The `0` argument is the identity, which is returned when the stream is empty.)

or even:

```
public int retrieveTotalHours(){
    return taskList.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getTaskHours()).sum();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down Hoopje

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically, an `Optional<Integer>` is not assignment compatible with `int`.

But `Integer` is (after unboxing) ... so change:

```
jProgressBar1.setValue(tL.retrieveTotalHours());
```

to

```
jProgressBar1.setValue(tL.retrieveTotalHours().orElse(0));
```

Note that you *must* provide an integer value when you call setValue.  Null or "nothing" is not acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - the orElse(0) did the trick! And yes this field must have a value over 0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the sum of hours, you don't need the Optional and can make it simpler:

```
public int retrieveTotalHours()
{
  return taskList.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getTaskHours()).sum();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roger - I will be doing this on another field so will try your method too